# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show a modal in my website on page load. But I got this error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

I have also tried with `jQuery` but also get the same type of error

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).modal is not a function

I have googling already several times and apply different solutions but not succeeded.

**Here is my script**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).on('load',function(){
      $('#loadModal').modal('show');
   });
</script>
```

**Here is my modal**

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="loadModal">
    <div class="modal-header">
         <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
         <h3>Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
         <p>One fine body…</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
         <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working here mate

Comment: It works fine - http://plnkr.co/edit/2ioUOGPNvWhCO9fMBH2K?p=preview

Comment: May be `bootstrap.min.js` is anyhow loaded in your machine. Open Developer tools (`F12`) and go to `network tab` then click on `disable cache` and hit refresh (`F5`)

Comment: actually I have used lots of script in my project ... may b this problem is created from those scripts orders....hows can I find out the order from those scripts !! ohh

Comment: Order also good.
jQuery library > bootstrap libraray > initialize

Comment: Probably your jQuery library is being blocked because your site is on https and that CDN `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js` is not. Save that file locally on server and reference from there.

Comment: no change of error....after locally saved that js file

Answer (score 10):

Solved !!! It's a order related problem.

**`bootstrap.min.js` should declared after 
 all `jQuery` libraries.**

Comment: pase 3 horas sin saber que hacer hasta q encontré tu solución y funcionoooooo muchas gracias

Comment: It worked this tip.

Answer (score 1):

1. jQuery must be referenced first, so you must call the jquery.min.js and then bootstrap.min.js. Try this :

   ```
    <script src="/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. Sometimes this warning may also be shown if jQuery is declared more than once in your code. The second jQuery declaration prevents bootstrap.js from working correctly. The problem is due to having jQuery instances more than one time. I have solved this problem with this code in jQuery :

   ```
    window.$('#modal-id').modal();
   ```

Comment: Meeeeu Deus cara, MUITO OBRIGADO, você salvou meu dia

Answer (score 1):

I added a modal dialog in **jsp** and tried to open it with javascript in **jsx** and hit the same error: **"...modal is not a function"**

In my case, simply by adding below import to the jsx solved the problem.

`import "./../bower/bootstrap/js/modal.js"; // or import ".../bootstrap.min.js"`

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap modal does not work well with `jQuery UI dialog`

The bootstrap Modal error is actually the result of you not including bootstrap's javascript before calling the modal function. Modal is defined in `bootstrap.js` and not in jQuery . It's also important to note that bootstrap actually needs jQuery to define the modal function , so it's vital that you include jQuery before including bootstrap's javascript. To avoid such error just be sure to include jQuery then bootstrap's javascript before you call the modal function.

Answer (score 0):

Your web page loading times will probably be very fast.
Then the modal('show') event is not bound in the selector tag.

It creates an error.

```
$(document).ready(function() { $("selectorName").modal('show'); });
```

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```